# FIFA - What are player cards and what are they used for?

Tags: fifa-15, fifa-16

I haven't played FIFA in a long time (about 5 years now) and I recently found out that you're able to get player cards. The question is, what are those cards used for and what exactly are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fifa Ultimate Team. You can read more about the 2016 version here: https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/features

Basically you build a squad of cards for playing against people online. There are different levels of cards including bronze, silver, gold, and special Team of the Week/Team of the Year cards that give stat boosts to players. In addition to player cards, there are also manager, contract and item cards that you use to keep your team together and healthy.

Comment: Thanks @Rome_Leader awesome explanation! But let's say you've a team of Ronaldo, Messi and few other giant players in your team. Can the opponent team also have those very players if they got it?

Comment: If you can afford these players, you must be one of the best FIFA players in the world! Or at least very rich :)

But to answer your general question, yes, there are multiples of players. In the case of Jermaine Defoe, there will likely be millions. In the case of world class players like Ronaldo, there are probably fewer as he is rare in packs. Players come from packs that are bought, either via in-game coins or real currency, or provided as tournament prizes, etc. But there is not only one of each

Feel free to accept my answer if it has helped you by clicking the checkmark to the left!